# Windows Phone 8.1 vocal synthesis

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, voice

I have a problem.

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app, I would implement a button function such that my phone tell "hello world" (by voice). I have already searched in the web dozens of solution, with the result: the instruction wasn't good for Win 8.1; the instruction has require external resources; the instruction gives me a lot of error.

Please, do you have a simple code to do this? Thank in advance!

Comment: Please include code and things you have tired to help others help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for Windows Phone 8.1, more info on [Speech Synthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    private async void TextToSpeech(string textToReadAloud)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer ttssynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        //Set the Voice & Speaker
        using (var speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            speaker.Voice = (SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Female));
            ttssynthesizer.Voice = speaker.Voice;
        }

        SpeechSynthesisStream ttsStream = await ttssynthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(textToReadAloud);
        MediaElement.SetSource(ttsStream, "");  
    }
```

Note MediaElement can be bound to a content control in your xaml.

```
            <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"         
            Width="320" Height="140" Content="{Binding MediaElement}"/>
```

Media Element declared in your view model.

```
    private MediaElement _mediaElement = new MediaElement();

    public MediaElement MediaElement
    {
        get
        {
            return _mediaElement;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => MediaElement, ref _mediaElement, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I apologize for this delay but I wasn't at my computer. Thank for you answer but it doesn't work. If I try exactly your code, I read an error message "A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in myApp.exe
WinRT information: Access is denied." Why? Thank.

Comment: Solved! The problem was enable microphone access. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx)?

For more information I suggest to watch the second lesson in MVA's course [Universal Windows App Development with Cortana and the Speech SDK](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/universal-windows-app-development-with-cortana-and-the-speech-sdk)

Comment: I haven't found a solution, I have tried a lot of code (see previous answer) but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Thank!

Comment: Solved! The problem was enable microphone access. Thank!